# Inside the usercontrol,get the element value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ext.net

I have a text control inside usercontrol(ascx) like this
*usercontrol is created  dynamically

```
     <ext:TextField runat="server" ID="txtIl" Flex="1" FieldLabel="Il"
 ClientIDMode="Static"></ext:TextField>
```

and in this user control have a js code like this

```
var getformdata = function () {

                var il = $("#<%=txtIl.ClientID%>").val();

                alert(il);
                alert(<%=txtIl.ClientID%>);


            };
```

and inside again same usercontrol have a button which call the js function(getformdata )

```
 `<ext:Button runat="server" Icon="Add" Text="Ekle" Handler="getformdata();"></ext:Button`>
```

my problem is the value of the text field is getting undefined value.
someone tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you post rendered HTML?

Comment: You should view the source and find out if this code actually has the right ID inside - `$("#<%=txtIl.ClientID%>").val();`

Comment: ext:TextField id come different.

Comment: var il = $("#<%=txtIl.ClientID%>").val(); this come undifine ,however the html code shows it is somethink like this;<input id="txtIl-inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="txtIl"......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
alert(App.txtIl.getValue())
```

to retrieve a TextField's value.

Comment: what the difference between the them,daniil.

Comment: Well, the IDMode property is supposed to be used in Ext.NET to manage how the IDs should be rendered. Though, it doesn't mean that ClientIDMode won't work. Ext.NET respects ClientIDMode as well. I am going to removed that part from my answer.